# How can I focus on an specific mat-tab

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material, mat-tab

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs #tabGroup (focusChange)="tabChanged($event)" [selectedIndex]="0">
    <mat-tab label="DATOS EXPEDIENTE">
      <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
        <app-informe-expediente></app-informe-expediente>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="DATOS ALTERACIÓN">
      <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
        <app-informe-alteracion></app-informe-alteracion>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="DATOS INMUEBLES">
      <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
        <app-informe-inmuebles></app-informe-inmuebles>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="FLUJO DE TRAMITACIÓN">
      <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
        <app-informe-tramitacion></app-informe-tramitacion>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="DOCUMENTOS ASOCIADOS">
      <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
        <app-informe-documentos></app-informe-documentos>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

This is my `mat-tab-group` that depends on a browser, so it triggers every time I click my submit button. I need to know how can I get the first tab with index 0 to get focused every time I click my submit button.
I know it has to do with index and that stuff but I don't know, I am controlling the indexes with  MatTabChangeEvent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use two way binding on `selectedIndex` to keep track of which tab is selected, and set `selectedIndex` to 0 on the button click

Template

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]=selectedIndex>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="selectedIndex = 0">
  Reset tab
</button>
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-basic-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-basic-example.html'
})
export class TabGroupBasicExample {
  selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: You save me !!! <3

Answer (score 5):

I try with `::ng-deep.mat-tab-label-active` and it works changing the opacity to 1.0 only to active focus tab.

You can use this code:

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label-active{
    opacity: 1.0!important;
}
```